# Compilation Issues for new views .scala.html to .class

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm new to the Play framework. I attempted to compile my play framework project following a sample. When I compile the sample, it works fine and has the .scala.html view compiled in the target as .class. I added a new view, but it didn't compile into the target. Any suggestions how to fix this? I tried activator compile with command line, cleaning and re-building the project, building .scala.html individually, but none of the attempts worked. How do you add a new view and compile it in Play 2.4?

```
package controllers;

import models.Client; 
import models.Server;
import models.TestEvent;
import models.TestPlan;

import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.formData.testFormData;

public class Application extends Controller {

// Default path request
// public Result index() {return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));}


/* Index Route Page
 * Returns the page where the form is filled with the arguments passed
 * Or an empty form if the id is 0
 */
public static Result getIndex(long id) {
    testFormData testData;
    // Find the corresponding index result to return (depends on the id)
    if(id == 0)
        testData = new testFormData();
    else
        testData = models.TestEvent.makeTestFormData(id);

    Form<testFormData> formData = Form.form(testFormData.class).fill(testData);
    return ok(index.render(formData,
            Client.getClientNameList(),
            Server.getServerNameList(),
            TestPlan.getTestPlanNameList()));
}


// Process a form submission
// Bind HTTP Post data to an instance of testFormData
// If errors are found, re-render the page displaying the error data
// If errors are not found, re-render the page displaying good data
public static Result postIndex() {
    // Retrieve the formData
    Form<testFormData> formData = Form.form(testFormData.class).bindFromRequest();

    // The retrieved formData has errors
    if(formData.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(index.render(formData,
                Client.getClientNameList(),
                Server.getServerNameList(),
                TestPlan.getTestPlanNameList()));
    }

    // The formData does not have errors
    else {
        // Convert the form data into a testEvent Instance
        TestEvent testEvent = TestEvent.makeTestEventInstance(formData.get());

        return ok(index.render(formData,
                Client.getClientNameList(),
                Server.getServerNameList(),
                TestPlan.getTestPlanNameList()));
    }
}
}
```

Routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.getIndex(id:Long ?= 0)

 POST    /                           controllers.Application.postIndex()



 # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
 GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Comment: Is your server running and do you have a controller action which returns the newly created view? What do you get when you try to call the controller action from a web browser? This also requires a change in routes.conf.

Comment: The error on the web browser is "value getIndex is not a member of controllers.Application" on: GET / controllers.Application.getIndex(id:Long ?= 0) I configured the routes.conf to match the action from the application.java file. But the views are not in the target.

Comment: Don't care about the view yet, either your routes are wrong or the controller. Controller is not invoked. Views are compiled when needed so try to fix this issue first.

Comment: The controller is the issue. In my IDE, the only error that I get is "Cannot resolve symbol 'index' ", where index is one of my views, which is why I went back to the issue of views. I attempted to import the views, but they also don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

If the server isn't running while you're coding, changes won't be compiled.  You can remedy this by turning on the continuous compilation feature, with compilation occurring every time a change is written to the file system.

To do this:

1. Start activator
2. Use `~compile`

The `~` indicates changes should be compiled immediately.

You can do something similar with the server.  By using `~run`, changes will be compiled immediately on file system changes and not delayed until the browser is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, the same error persists.